# CSS, use @supports to detect @font-face support

Tags: css, font-face

Is it possible to use `@supports` to check if the client's browser supports `'@font-face`?

My goal is to use several `@font-face` by default, and if it's not supported, then fallback to another `font-family` definitions instead.

I've tried the following (see code below); it works, but I wonder if it's legal and/or conform to standards, and if it really does what I'm expecting.

```css
/* Yes, I don't use an actual font-face, but it's irrelevant for the test */
.ff {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

@supports not (@font-face) {
  .ff {
    font-family: serif;
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/idealtitude/5gxf2ojs/7/

Any idea, suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: Is this necessary in practice? See https://caniuse.com/?search=font-face

Comment: @AHaworth I was asking my self the question as well... But, even if font-face is widely supported, and it's unlikely that I have to worry about that, I'd still want to write my CSS with that conditionnal ability. I was also considering giving the user the choice to switch font-face and regular font families.

Comment: This is unnecessary. `font-family` already supports fallback like `font-family: FakeFontName, sans-serif;` In this example, if you define the font-face of the FakeFontName and the browser does not support it, it will fallback to sans-serif. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-family

Comment: @skyline3000 I think that's the way to go to solve my problem. Simple, clear and conform to the spec. Thank you!

Comment: Worth noting/fun fact: `@font-face` was widely adopted by browsers even before the `@supports` rule was. See [caniuse statistics](https://caniuse.com/?search=%40supports). So we're not really talking about reasonable legacy browser support, but about Internet Explorer compatibility, which is still torturing developers to this day due to some quirky embedded systems relying on this eco-system.

Answer (score 1):

The question asks whether the code is legal and whether it does what you are expecting.

Well, it doesn't do what you are expecting.

If you keep the not in then on my browser (which does support font-face) the font shows as serif.

If I remove the not then it shows as sans serif. i.e it appears to be reporting that the browser does not support font-face.

```css
.ff {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

@supports (@font-face) {
  .ff {
    font-family: serif;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="ff">What are you seeing here??</div>
```

What can you do to test if @font-face is supported? I suppose a simplistic way would be to load some text with a font-face rule which is very different from the font-face you expect to be used as a standard and then see if the size comes out any different.

Comment: Nice advice! I was quite sure something's not right in my logic, you helped me clarified it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
@supports (@font-face) { ... }
```

and

```
@supports not (@font-face) { ... }
```

Does not work to test if the browser supports @font-face. Both of those are invalid CSS. Currently, you can't use @supports to test support for at-rules. See [MDN @supports documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports) for proper @supports syntax and for what it can test.